# Need help for run charm-server in local server?

Tags: server, juju

Hi i need to run juju charm-store in my local machine.i clone this one(https://github.com/juju/charmstore) and try to run the server.but it failed.i want to install juju-server and build environment for maintain juju-charms locally.I want simple guide for doing this.First of all i want to know is this possible.In simply i want to run juju charm-store server and then developers can deploy their charms to our charm-store.

Thanks
Sajith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible for the juju client to use a different URL for the charm store. It's hardcoded to use "https://store.juju.ubuntu.com". If you want to change that, you have to change the value in a forked version of the juju/charm package and rebuild Juju from source.

Then, if you read the README.md (available rendered here - https://github.com/juju/charmstore), you can see the steps needed to clone the charmstore locally, import charms from launchpad, and then run the server.